# Two container divs causing sidebar to not float properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar

http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/product-category/shop/

My site contains two container divs. An inner and an outer(which contains the whole site). I am trying to float my sidebar(which is displayed under my content div) to the left of the content div by reducing the width to 710px. however, the outer container is limiting how my sidebar floats left. How do i fix the two containers so my content is still centered and my sidebar is floated left.

[image]

## SIDEBAR

```
*************************************************************************/

#sidebar{

position:relative;

z-index:10;

width:270px;
 display:block;
 float:left

}
```

Comment: did you try display:inline-block;

Comment: yes i did try that @Keith

Comment: so you want your sidebar to be up top and next to the container id?

Comment: @Keith I want the sidebar to be postioned on the right side of my content div

Comment: oh well your content div is too wide, that is why your sidebar is floating up and to the right.

Comment: i know, im resizing the conent and inner container div to 710px then floating the content div but its not working properly because of the outer container div @Keith

Comment: the outer div needs to equal the widths of the inner divs, so if your outer div is 1000 and your content div is 700, then your sidebar cant be more than 300

Comment: @Keith when i shrink the width of the divs it floats everything to the left http://i.imgur.com/P7WKUwS.jpg

Comment: there is no more centered content on my page then @Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your container this styling:

```
#container{
display: inline-block;
width: 600px; 
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And give your sidebar this styling:

```
#sidebar{
float: right;
}
```

Your sidebar will now align to the right and your container to the left. Do you mean this? I just give the overfow hidden because you have to many colums at the moment.

Picture: http://s15.postimg.org/5gpgxzfaz/example.png

**EDIT:**

You can set this styling on the ul [products].

```
ul.products {
float: left;
width: 700px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can give this options to the sidebar.

```
#sidebar{
float: right;
}
```

Now it should working.

Comment: Close but it floats all content to the left. the content is no longer centered. http://i.imgur.com/P7WKUwS.jpg

Comment: Put your products in a other div? And give that div the styling options? That should working. I have edited my first post. Try that.

Comment: its floating part of my footer under the sidebar now

Comment: You have a div with this styling options: `height: 200px; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; margin-bottom: 30px;` just add on each one this options: `clear: both;`. This will center your text again if you mean that.